# Add Bootstrap style to working search box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change the style on a working search box to match the theme.

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
</div>
<!-- /input-group -->
<div class="search_box">
  <form id="form_search" name="form_search" method="get" action="<?php echo site_url();?>">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search_top" />
    <input type="button" name="btn1" id="btn_top" value="" />
  </form>
</div>
```

The first div is the style I need, the second is the working search box.

Respectively, here is what each looks like currently:
http://gyazo.com/ecd1b696f723879d5512588b1d384017

Comment: Clear your point..How you want...you want separate search_box div

Comment: `<div class="input-group">
<form id="form_search" name="form_search" method="get" action="<?php echo site_url();?>">
 <input type="text" name="s" id="search_top"  class="form-control"/>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btn_top">Go!</button>
</form>
</div>`

Comment: So that works, however the button doesn't work. (You can press enter to search) Code: <div class="input-group"> 
      <form id="form_search" name="form_search" method="get" action="<?php echo site_url();?>"> 
       <input type="text" name="s" id="search_top" class="form-control"/> 
       <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn_top" value=""> 
      </form> 
     </div>

Comment: $('#btn_top').click(function(e) {
     $('#form_search').submit();
});

Answer (score 0):

Manage the width of your parent container as per your requirement, but the get the search bar, as you are showing: check the linked fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/happy2deepak/d4jad6ah/

```
 <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Go!</button>
    </span>
 </div>
```